# macOS Sierra Download Time Est 33 hours

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I have tested my network download speed (hit 132 Mbps, but that was to server within 100 miles), changed the DNS server address to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, restarted my macbook, but the download time will not change! Please tell me there is something else I can do to fix this. I expected some extra download time with everyone upgrading, but this is ridiculous -- it is 2016, right?

Thanks

Comment: Patience, just patience. Everybody and her grandmother is downloading Sierra right now, So the servers might be kind of swamped.

Comment: yeah 2016, but no one has thousands  of gigabytes  of bandwidth, not even IBM! or google! and if IBM doesn't, Apple doesn't either. Though, google may do. possibly, I'm not sure, though it sounds plausible.

Comment: It's a recurring issue… Used their [feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) on 2017-04-13 and again today to let them know about the issue, but it never got any better. Download is at 10x/20x what my connection can handle… And only happens with them. Downloading from, say, AWS is super fast.

Answer (score 4):

Servers are busy, try at another time of day, not when America is awake & the EU are all home for dinner.

I got mine in about 40 mins, at around 8am, GMT

It has nothing to do with what DNS servers you use. Once you're connected, DNS is not even relevant. Your own ISP's DNS would normally be faster anyway, as it's [theoretically] optimised for your connection.

Rebooting your router/modem & all network hardware, then your Mac may help a bit, fresh everything up.

Comment: Well, even months later… A 2h30 estimate to download 4.95 GB on a connection that can handle it in 34 min… That's just not good. Apple should probably add some ‘muscle’ behind their servers.

Comment: 5GB for me would normally be just over 5 mins, assuming my connection to whatever local CDN is good. You cannot sweepingly declare "Apple's servers" to be slow. They don't operate 'servers' as you think of them, they use a worldwide distributed content delivery network. There are a million reasons for you to get a slow connection, but the CDN is one of the least likely except for right on a new major release.

Answer (score 2):

this always happens, think of the size of the update, imagine thousands of people doing that at once, hundreds of gigabytes, will rack up very fast, give them time, and your update will be with you, in time, the best time is to leave it to update at US nighttime, when the servers are at the least load.